# I am using primefaces datatable but when I sort I see sorted values on screen but pagesource still shows original values

Tags: primefaces, datatable

When I sort on column value of commandLink on screen comes as sorted but when I do page source it's value is still showing original value which was before sort.

```
<p:dataTable var="event" value="#eventTableBean.searchEvents()}" paginator="true" 
rows="3" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} 
{PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} 
{RowsPerPageDropdown}">

<p: columnsortBy="#{event.alertStatus}" headerText="Alert Status" 
style="white-space: normal;">

<h: commandLinkactionListener="#{eventController.updateEvent}"
style="#{event.color}; font-weight: bold"value="#{event.alertStatus}">

<f: attributename="updateEvent" value="#{event}"/>

</h: commandLink>

</p: column>
```

Comment: Why are you looking at the page source?

Comment: I was just curious about why I am getting different values in my controller. So I checked doing view page source in browser to see how data is populated in datatable. and I found it is different then what I see on screen and same as what I get in my controller.